# why my items are not showing in wishlist in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am working on an application where I want to add items in the wishlist section. I have some data which I am fetching from the firestore in recyclerview on each item I have a heart icon when someone clicks on that icon that particular item should be added to the wishlist section. I am new to android please guide me on how can I achieve this or refer to any document thank you

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: yes sir i have added the checkbutton on the recycler view each item and then set on click listener on that but from now on I have no idea how can I achieve that

Comment: Show us the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Check if the check button is working. Check if the data is getting added in firestore DB. If it is added, then check the method you have used to fetch the data and then show it as a wishlist. Show here what you have tried so far.

Comment: @RobertS hello sir actually i have not tried anything till now can you please tell me steps to achieve this I am new and confused.

Comment: @VivekMFauzdar you can refer this example - https://github.com/alexmamo/Firestore-ShoppingListApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following thing -

1. Create one collection name with **Wishlist**
2. When the user clicks on a particular Item heart and adds respective data with the Item Id and userId in **Wishlist** collection, It will create one document.
3. Fetch data from Wishlist collection to show user wishlist using a query like get data from Wishlist collection by userId using where clause.

Comment: thank you Aditya brother for your response your solution is working fine but the problem is how can I get the item id??

Comment: You need to save that while creating a post, And pass the same Id while adding to the wishlist.

Comment: brother sorry for that but actually i am newbie so i have created the login system with phone number but i did not connect the firebase auth and firebase firestore because i don know that